# Select rows of data frame based on a vector with duplicated values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

What I want can be described as: give a data frame, contains all the case-control pairs. In the following example, y is the id for the case-control pair. There are 3 pairs in my data set. I'm doing a resampling with respect to the different values of y (the pair will be both selected or neither).

```
sample_df = data.frame(x=1:6, y=c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
> sample_df
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 1
3 3 2
4 4 2
5 5 3
6 6 3
select_y = c(1,3,3)
select_y
> select_y
[1] 1 3 3
```

Now, I have computed a vector contains the pairs I want to resample, which is `select_y` above. It means the case-control pair number 1 will be in my new sample, and number 3 will also be in my new sample, but it will occur 2 times since there are two 3. The desired output will be:

```
x y
1 1
2 1
5 3
6 3
5 3
6 3
```

I can't find out an efficient way other than writing a for loop...

Solution:
Based on @HubertL , with some modifications, a 'vectorized' approach looks like:

```
sel_y <- as.data.frame(table(select_y))
> sel_y
  select_y Freq
1        1    1
2        3    2
sub_sample_df = sample_df[sample_df$y%in%select_y,]
> sub_sample_df
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 1
5 5 3
6 6 3
match_freq = sel_y[match(sub_sample_df$y, sel_y$select_y),]
> match_freq
    select_y Freq
1          1    1
1.1        1    1
2          3    2
2.1        3    2
sub_sample_df$Freq = match_freq$Freq
rownames(sub_sample_df) = NULL
sub_sample_df
> sub_sample_df
  x y Freq
1 1 1    1
2 2 1    1
3 5 3    2
4 6 3    2
selected_rows = rep(1:nrow(sub_sample_df), sub_sample_df$Freq)
> selected_rows
[1] 1 2 3 3 4 4
sub_sample_df[selected_rows,]
    x y Freq
1   1 1    1
2   2 1    1
3   5 3    2
3.1 5 3    2
4   6 3    2
4.1 6 3    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method of doing the same without a loop:

```
sample_df = data.frame(x=1:6, y=c(1,1,2,2,3,3))

row_names <- split(1:nrow(sample_df),sample_df$y)

select_y = c(1,3,3)

row_num <- unlist(row_names[as.character(select_y)])

ans <- sample_df[row_num,]
```

Comment: I have to say it's a better solution. That's a good use of split.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way without a loop, but at least it's not a `for` loop, and there is only one iteration per frequency:

```
sample_df = data.frame(x=1:6, y=c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
select_y = c(1,3,3)
sel_y <- as.data.frame(table(select_y))
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(1:max(sel_y$Freq), 
               function(freq) sample_df[sample_df$y %in% 
                              sel_y[sel_y$Freq>=freq, "select_y"],]))

   x y
1  1 1
2  2 1
5  5 3
6  6 3
51 5 3
61 6 3
```

Comment: Yeah, that's similar to what i'm doing right now. For a large data set, the speed still concerns. I'm thinking a better way is to create a freq variable, which stands for the frequency of the pair. For example, I can first decide the pair 1 and 3 need to be selected, then I decide 3 need to be selected twice, then the freq=rep(c(1,3), c(1,2)), something like this. And sample_df[freq, ] will do the job. However, I don't have an efficient way doing so.

Comment: based on your hint, I think I come up with a better one. See above. Thank you, what a team work. @HubertL